# Kestrel and https very slow

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server

I am using Rider from JetBrains and it made me realize that configuring https directly through Kestrel makes the requests to API very slow. I have the same behaviour if I just run

```
dotnet MyApi.dll
```

When I am using Visual Studio and running the API on IIS Express I don't have any performance issues.
This is how I configured Kestrel to listen on https

```
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My))
{
   store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
   var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "localhost", false);
   cert = certs[0];
}
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseKestrel(options =>
{
   options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 44317, listenOptions =>
    {
         listenOptions.UseHttps(cert);
    });
 })
 .UseStartup<Startup>()
 .Build();
```

I tried to remove the https and just use http, and it is working as fast as with IIS Express. So it tells me that there is something wrong with the way I am configuring https. 
Is there any configuration I am missing that is making the Kestrel slower when https is activated or is it simply better to run it on IIS Express ?

Comment: I get this exact same issue as well. It increases my requests more than double. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: No sorry. The reason i was doing this is because I was using JetBrain's Rider and there was no IIS Express support. I just switched back to VS